# How can I restrict an external script to users that are logged in as an Administrator?

Tags: session, joomla, joomla2.5

I am creating a new page that is getting redirected from the Administrator page in Joomla 2.5.The page is getting displayed when i type the URL in browser . I need to restrict the view such that it can be visible only when the administrator logs into his account . Can you help me on this ?

This is my code:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($app->isAdmin()) echo 'Running from Joomla Administrator site <Br/>';

//$app->isAdmin() always through null value

print_r($user);

echo $user->username;
```

When i login from my site this code works perfectly but when i login using 
administrator interface this code display's null value. i don't know why. is there any 
mistake in it?
I get this output when i login using Administrator interface:

```
   JUser Object
   (
       [isRoot:protected] => 
       [id] => 0
       [name] => 
       [username] => 
       [email] => 
       [password] => 
       [password_clear] => 
       [usertype] => 
       [block] => 
       [sendEmail] => 0
       [registerDate] => 
       [lastvisitDate] => 
       [activation] => 
       [params] => 
       [groups] => Array
       (
        )

       [guest] => 1
       [lastResetTime] => 
       [resetCount] =>
```

when i login as a site user from my site (member login) i get this:

```
       JUser Object
      (
          [isRoot:protected] => 
          [id] => 2
          [name] => name of user
          [username] => username
          [email] => username@gmail.com
          [password] => 695c263968014c89bbf3159aa4:YoBWR6uzmUBMcqfj5hPzCIp7a6maYd
          [password_clear] => 
          [usertype] => 
          [block] => 0
          [sendEmail] => 1
          [registerDate] => 2014-11-24
          [lastvisitDate] => 2014-11-25 15:29:45
          [activation] => 
          [params] => {}
          [groups] => Array
          (
              [2] => 2
          )

          [guest] => 0
```

I suffering with this problem for last 8 days.  can you help me with this..

Comment: Clarify the question...is this script being executed BY the logged in administrator, OR is it supposed to "do something" if an admin is logged in at all?  If so, does it matter if they're logged into the main site or logged into the admin site?

Comment: I creating a report page for the administrator. i just need to check whether admin logged in or not from administrator login. i just put this file into administrator folder. Is it right? or i have to write this page any where else in administrator folder..?

Comment: I added a variation for use in Admin - when you run it from there, you have to get the $app as 'administrator', not 'site'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you're loading Joomla to start with (See [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2510/when-accessing-joomla-from-an-external-script-when-should-you-include-librarie) at Joomla Stackexchange),

**Update** Added complete script.

Save this code in a php file located in the root of your Joomla folder.  It will work, and you'll see the output.  From there, you can adapt it's location and such to work with whatever you're trying to accomplish.

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
}
defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->groups;

if ($app->isSite()) echo 'Running from Joomla Front End site<Br/>';
if ($app->isAdmin()) echo 'Running from Joomla Administrator site <Br/>';
if($user->id) {
    echo $user->username.' is logged in<Br/>';
    if (isset($groups[8])) echo " - User is a Super User <Br/>";
    if (isset($groups[7])) echo " - User is an Administrator <Br/>";
    if (isset($groups[6])) echo " - User is an Manager <Br/>";
}else{
    echo 'Not logged in<Br/>';
}

if(!isset($groups[7])) die("You must be an administrator to run this");
```

**VARIATION FOR USE IN `\administrator`**

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
    defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

//$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
if ($app->isSite()) echo 'Running from Joomla Front End site<Br/>';
if ($app->isAdmin()) echo 'Running from Joomla Administrator site <Br/>';

$user = JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id) {
    echo $user->username.' is logged in<Br/>';
    $groups = $user->groups;
    if(isset($groups[8])) {
        die("You are a Super User - only Administrators can run this");
        // Do your superuser coding here
    }elseif(isset($groups[7])) {
        die("You are an administrator - you can run this");
        // Do your admin coding here
    }
}else{
    echo 'Not logged in<Br/>';
}
```

Comment: Just updated the answer with a fully functional script that works from the root of the joomla site.  You have all you need now.

Comment: isSite() is set but isAdmin is not set even Administrator logged in... Can you say how to check whether administrator logged in or not..?

Comment: isSite/isAdmin is regarding whether user is logged into frontend or backend of site.  I've added how to determine which usergroups the users is in.  Table #__usergroups contains these groups, so you can check for any kind of usergroup you'd like.

Comment: Can you specify the exact file or folder location where this code has to be placed. It will be very helpful for me. And its not created of an extension it is core php page. inside administrator folder. I need to restrict this page from non Administrator(Superadmin)...                                        Can you help me with this.. thanks in advance...

Comment: This particular piece of code would have to be in the root of your joomla site so that it can find those files, but I've run the same code from a multitude of locations after adjusting that.

Comment: Dear GDP.. I can get the member details with this code.. But i need to check whether administrator logged in or not.. Can u say where the administrator session maintained in joomla? Sorry for bothering you this much..

Comment: isAdmin says the user is logged in the the administrator site , and /or if (isset($groups[7])) say is the logged in user IS an administrator or not.  Together you can tell if the user is an admin or not, and whether or not they're logged into the front/end or back/end.

Comment: I added the single line of code you need at the end

Comment: Why UNaccept the answer from @GDP? - he's written the code for you.

Comment: I added my code what i have done and the output.. can you guide me through this?

Comment: Where in your joomla site is this script of yours located?

Comment: Awesome... Thanks a lot... Your a genius GDP. Thanks for your patience and guidance for me thanks a lot......